# Как сохранить текст в массив из каждой колонки в таблице SQlite в JavaFX приложении?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

Делаю приложение на JavaFX. База данных SQLite.

Есть таблица "category1" и поля в ней: "ID", "question, "answer"

[image: table]

В главном окне у меня есть два лейбла. Когда запускаю приложение, заполняю базу данных. У меня в приложении реализована функция добавления текстов, удаления, или редактирования. Количество рядов в базе SQlite будет постоянно меняться.

Мне нужно сохранить текст из каждой колонки в массив(какой-либо список из фреймворка коллекции) Текст из колонки question связан с текстом из колонки "answer" для каждого ряда в таблице.

Если я нажму, к примеру цифру 1 на клавиатуре, то один рандомный вопрос из массива должен появиться в первом лейбле, а соответствующий ему ответ должен появиться в другом лейбле. После того, как тексты появятся, они должны быть удалены из массива. Другими словами, каждый раз, как я нажимаю на цифру 1, в лейблах должны появляться разные рандомные вопросы из таблицы, но дубликатов не должно быть. Поэтому и хочу их из массива сразу удалять.

Если я закрою программу и открою снова, массивы должны заполниться вопросами автоматически из таблицы.

**Как создать массивы для текстов из таблицы SQLite, которые будут автоматически обновляться?**

Лейблы:

```
@FXML  private Label lb_randomCard, lb_randomCardBack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен список `List<Category>` или удобнее может оказаться мапа `Map<Integer, Category>`. В объекте категории три поля соответствующий таблицы,  ключом для карты использует `ID`. Заполняете выбранную коллекцию из базы, тем способом, которым вы извлекаете данные из базы, а дальше удаляйте из коллекций элементы.

Comment: я не понимаю как применить данные из таблицы к интерфейсу Map. Map имеет два параметра: ключ и значение, но у меня 3 параметра в таблице: ID, question, answer. Можете привести пример использования map с одним рядом из таблицы?

Comment: `map.put(id, new Category(id, question, answer));`

Comment: спасибо! попробую)